# Create symlinks for duplicate images

Tags: image, catalog-optimize

Is there a possibility to create symlinks for duplicate images instead of adding another file?

If there is a grouped product which has the same image as the related products magento will add another file for each of the products. But the images are identical. This causes magento to use a lot of diskspace. Is there a module or shelscript which copes with this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this PHP script](https://gist.github.com/peterjaap/5547654) which claims to do the following:

- Removes references to non-existing images
- Removes duplicate images
- Sets correct default image
- Deletes orphaned images from the filesystem

I have not tested it, but it looks like it'll address your concerns.  I highly recommend testing it on a cloned copy of your website first and/or taking a full backup of your database and `media` directory, in case anything goes wrong.